# Niveau von "entweder .. oder .. oder .." bzw. "weder .. noch .. noch .."

Tags: usage, style

Wie formell klingen die Konstruktionen

> entweder .. oder .. oder ..

beziehungsweise

> weder .. noch .. noch ..

auf Deutsch? Könnte man diese in der schriftlichen Sprache verwenden, oder sollte man sie lieber vermeiden?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meiner Meinung nach spricht nichts dagegen, solange man beachtet, verständliche und nicht zu lange Sätze damit zu bilden. Zudem sollten längere Aufzählungen und Wiederholungen vermieden werden, so dass die Verwendung von mehr als zwei "oder" bzw. "noch" nur noch selten elegant klingen dürfte.

Für mich wären z.B. folgende Sätze gleichwertig und sowohl mündlich als auch schriftlich in Ordnung:

> Ich habe weder ein Haus noch ein Auto noch ein Boot.
>
> Ich habe kein Haus, kein Auto und auch kein Boot.

Comment: Ergänzend wäre noch anzumerken, dass man bei *entweder … oder* problemlos eine Komma-Aufzählung benutzen kann, z.B.: *Entweder A, B, C oder D*

Answer (score 1):

Sowohl "entweder ... oder ... " als auch "weder ... noch ..." sind Standard-Deutsch und werden im alltäglich Gesprochenen als auch in guter Schriftsprache verwendet.

Man kann ohne Sinn oder Betonungsverlust sie auch nicht durch eine einfache Aufzählung mit "oder" bzw. "und" ersetzen:

Ein "entweder" impliziert und betont, dass die folgende Aufzählung eine vollständige Liste einander ausschließende Optionen ist. Genau eine der Optionen kann und muss zutreffen.

Bei einer Formulierung mit "weder ... noch ... noch ..." trifft keine der aufgezählten Möglichkeiten zu. Der inhaltliche Unterschied zu einer einfach verneinten Aufzählung ist hier in der Betonung, dass alles gleichzeitig zutrifft. Auch schafft das "weder ... noch" eine elegante sprachliche Klammer, die schon am Beginn der Aufzählung aufgemacht wird und diese Liste als ganzes semantisch auf eine im Kontext vorausgehende oder folgende Begründungen verweisen kann.

Answer (score 0):

"Entweder — oder" und "Weder — noch" weisen explizit auf zwei Möglichkeiten hin, nicht auf drei oder mehr. Das geht schon aus der Etymologie dieses Wortpaars hervor: "Entweder" bedeutet seit seinem westgotischen Ursprung "eines von beiden", "oder" in zumindest einem seiner Bestandteile "diese beiden"*). Im modernen Gebrauch kann sich diese Zweiteilung wohl auch auf zwei Kategorien mit mehr als einem Beispiel beziehen, wie

> Ich habe weder *ein Haus* noch *ein Auto oder ein Boot*.

Gibt es mehr als zwei Alternativen, ist das entweder nicht nötig, oder die Konstruktion wird in eine "oder"-Reihe eingeschlossen:

> Entweder du forderst eine Gehaltserhöhung oder suchst dir einen besseren Job, oder du schränkst deine Ausgaben ein.

Wenn man das "entweder" weglässt:

> Du forderst eine Gehaltserhöhung, suchst dir einen besseren Job oder schränkst deine Ausgaben ein.

*) Kluge. Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache. Bearb. v. Elmar Seebold. Berlin, New York: de Gruyter (24) 2002

Comment: Ich finde das Beispiel mit entweder am Anfang viel besser. Da klingt der Satz wie eine Reihe von Vorschlägen. Das Beispiel ohne entweder klingt wie eine Reihe von Befehlen.